# Check if FTP is online/offline

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ping, ftp-server

What is the best way to determine if a ftp server is online or offline in Visual Basic?
I have tried many different ways of pinging the ftp server, but whatever I try, I get this error:

```
An exception occurred during a Ping request.
```

Is this easily fixable?  Or is there a better method than what I'm using?

Comment: There is no point in pinging before the FTP request.  The FTP request will return an error if at anytime the server goes down or does not respond.

Comment: Is your intention solely to see if you can get a response from the FTP server - or do you plan to do anything else afterwards, such as making an attempt to connect to it?

Comment: @dbasnett can you please give a quick example, not sure if i understand it the right way.

Comment: @DaveH well i want it to check if the FTP server is online to upload/download files, right now i can upload/download fine, but if the server goes down, the program crashes.

Comment: Is the FTP connection going to be left open for the duration of the program, or will you be connecting and disconnecting for each action? Depending on how you maintain your connection, you can look at the state of the connection to determine whether you are connected or not.

Comment: @DaveH When there is a file in the folder, it will connect to the FTP and upload that and then disconnect. So yeah, it will be connecting and disconnecting.

Comment: Posting the code you are using would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using webrequest, try this code i found

Hi, this should work fine:

```
Imports System.Net

    Dim request = _
    DirectCast(WebRequest.Create _
    ("ftp://ftp.example.com/folder_here/"), FtpWebRequest)

    request.Credentials = _
    New NetworkCredential("user_here", "pass_here")

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

    Try
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = _
        DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            ' Folder exists here
            MsgBox("exists!")
        End Using

    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = _
        DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
        'Does not exist
        If response.StatusCode = _
        FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
            MsgBox("Doesn't exist!")
        End If
    End Try
```

..the idea is that we use FtpWebRequest class and pass the folder name with a trailing slash "/", if the folder is found then the response will be processed fine inside Try-Catch block, if the folder could not be found, we handle the exception controlling with statusCode (ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable) to determine if absence of folder causes exception. That should work fine.

[Sources First answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12e8de79-c544-4164-8c4e-0ba75fb9096f/check-ftp-directory)

--------------- **Please also Try** ----------------------

```
Public Function CheckIfFtpFileExists(ByVal fileUri As String) As Boolean
   Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(fileUri)
   request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize
      Try
       Dim response As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
       ' THE FILE EXISTS
   Catch ex As WebException
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = ex.Response
        If FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable = response.StatusCode Then
            ' THE FILE DOES NOT EXIST
            Return False
        End If
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Get’s called like this:

```
If CheckIfFtpFileExists("ftp://ftp.domain.com/filename.txt") Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

[Sources](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/163632/How-to-check-if-a-file-exists-on-an-FTP-server)

Comment: Your welcome :) please feel free to Vote up and mark as Correct if you feel it satisfies your question.

Comment: Hey one more thing: when my server is offline and statusCode (ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable) is used, the program stops responding for like 15 sec and then starts responding again but no MsgBox is shown. Feels like it catches the exception but doesnt really execute the statusCode (ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable) ?

Comment: Maybe some kind of threading would help? Never done anything with threading, just starting to look into that.

Comment: I would agree and you can look into one of my many posts about Multithreading, this one is probably the easiest to follow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867358/textbox-doesnt-get-updated-while-threading/17868545#17868545 - Just place your code in the Tread. Since you are not using Gui calls leave out the Delegate Invoke, unless you want to get fancy ( makes it nice updating a label on your program from the thread ) if you have issues let me know we can talk tomorrow about threading.

Comment: I don't know what is the best way of contacting you here, so for now i will use this comment box.
I was wondering if i can put several threads under a single timer? For example: Timer1 starts Thread1 and Thread2 at the same time? Would that work or each timer can hold only one thread?

Comment: You can put 15 threads into 1 timer if you wanted ... problem is CPU power depending on how heavy the work is. :) but certainly you can !

Answer (score 1):

can you not just do this:

```
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("IP HERE") Then
        ' Success
    Else
        'fail
    End If
```

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Well it works with a normal ip, but it still gives the same error when i type in a ftp server: ftp://example.dyndns-server.com/

Comment: but is pinging the only way?

Comment: IP is The best way , other then ( Checking for a folder on the FTP server ) if exists  conection = good ( if you know this folder will always be there anyway ) in my opinion although Steven Liekens idea is pretty sweet aswell, seem as though if it fails you can build in a Retry or w/e else have you

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle i do know a folder that is always there, but how should i do it exactly? any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you write your code in a way that assumes that everything is perfect, then add error handling for cases where the connection fails.

Verifying whether the server is online beforehand does not guarantee that it will stay that way for the duration of the user session.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)newBuddyOnline:(NSString *)buddyName {

[onlineBuddies addObject:buddyName];
[self.TableView reloadData];

}

- (void)buddyWentOffline:(NSString *)buddyName {

[onlineBuddies removeObje`
`ct:buddyName];
[self.TableView reloadData];
}
```

This may helps .

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.